# I have a simple gridview, it's not displaying data

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dataset

My gridview source code is following

```
<asp:GridView ID="g1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

and my code behind is,

```
bindGridView(ds.Tables[0], g1, lblErrorActivityGrid, lblActivityGridCount);

private void bindGridView(DataTable dt, GridView grd, Label lblError, Label GrdRowCount)
    {
        grd.DataSource = dt;
        grd.DataBind();
    }
```

my question is why my gridview is not displaying data?
I am using dataset and manually adding data in my dataset and then returning table at 0th table.

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check your table has data or not ?

Comment: yes my table has data

Answer (score 2):

In markup set `AutogenerateColumns="true"` :

```
<asp:GridView ID="g1" AutoGenerateColumns= "true" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

**Here's how I have tested your code:**

In my markup I have the gridview.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:GridView ID="g1" AutoGenerateColumns= "true" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblErrorActivityGrid" runat="server" Text="Error Activity Grid"></asp:Label>        
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblActivityGridCount" runat="server" Text="Activity Grid Count"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In my code, in page load I am adding a DataTable to a DataSet and calling `bindGridView` method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(string));
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            DataRow nw = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
            nw[0] = (i + 1).ToString();
            nw["Column1"] = (i + 1).ToString();
            nw["Column2"] = String.Format("Item {0}", i);
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(nw);
        }
        bindGridView(ds.Tables[0], g1, lblErrorActivityGrid, lblActivityGridCount);
    }
}


private void bindGridView(DataTable dt, GridView grd, Label lblError, Label GrdRowCount)
{
    grd.DataSource = dt;
    grd.DataBind();
}
```

And here's the grid shows in my browser:

[image]

Comment: Set a breakpoint at `grd.DataSource = dt;` and see the data in `dt`. If it is empty, set a breakpoint at`bindGridView(ds.Tables[0], g1, lblErrorActivityGrid, lblActivityGridCount);` and see `ds` in dataset viewer. Check if this is the table you wnat to bind with gridview.

Comment: my datatable is not empty. It's full. It has many records. more than 50 records

Comment: Why do you say more than 50 records? In debug, in breakpoint at `grd.DataSource = dt;` it shows exact number of records. Did you check there? To make sure that you are accessing correct table from dataset.

Comment: Have you somewhere set the visibility of your gridview as false?..:)

Comment: well, what I am saying is that it's showing records. So it is not empty

Comment: For testing, change your code to this: var lst = new List<string>(){"1", "2"}; grd.DataSource=lst; grd.DataBind();` and check if the grid is visible.

Comment: AutogenerateColumns="true" is the default value. The issue should be somewhere else

Comment: All I could figure out was that my grd.DataBind() method is not functioning properly

Comment: @fwd - can you send your project so that I can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Try to Set

`grd.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;`

you must set the View to the Gridview from the DataTable..

Make sure the Table has Data.

Comment: I have tried grd.DataSource=dt.DefaultView;
It's still not working